# How to allow only an IP, Google Structured Data Testing Tool, and the W3C Markup Validation Service to access a website, while it's being developed?

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent, google-search-console, w3c-validation

I'm trying to develop, test, and debug a website's CSS, and PHP code, and block the public from seeing any of the websites pages (by redirecting them to a parked *"maintenance"* page), while the site is still being developed. This site is NOT a WordPress site, so the problem is NOT solvable by simply applying a plugin. However it *may* be solvable by using `.htaccess`, if it's configured correctly.

I'm using the following code in the`.htaccess` file in the root of my websites tree:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Allow the developer(s) (set to example.com's IP address for demonstration purposes) access to the website, via their IP address. #
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(93\.184\.216\.34)

# Allow users access to the directory containing the pages that handle HTTP error codes. #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\/(error_documents)\/.+$ [NC]

# Allow users access to the parked "maintenance" page (duh!). #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\/park\/index\.php$ [NC]

# During development and maintenance periods, redirect all others to the parked "maintenance" page. #
RewriteRule .* /park/index.php [R=302,L]

</IfModule>
```

Now, this works perfectly fine for it's intended purpose, but now I have (2) new problems:

- It also blocks the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), which I need to give access to for testing the websites "Structured Data".
- It also blocks the [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org), which I need to give access to, to check the markup's validity.

In order to solve these (2) problems, the following has to be accomplished:

- Figure out the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string the aforementioned (2) services are using, to access the website, and specifically *allow* those user agents (i.e. In consistency with the `.htaccess` code block, above, check that the request is **NOT** coming from those (2) services. If it is, then be sure **NOT** to redirect them to the parked "maintenance" page).

To give you an initial starting-point clue, that directive might look a little something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^GoogSDTT
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^W3CValidator
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to my question (with a little bit of online research):

With help from [this page](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/google-structured-data-testing-tool/), and [this page](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/w3c-validator/), from [whatismybrowser.com](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com), I was able to come up with the following `.htaccess` directive:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Allow the developer(s) (set to example.com's IP address for demonstration purposes) access to the website, via their IP address. #
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(93\.184\.216\.34)

# Allow access from [ Google Structured Data Testing Tool ]. #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(Google\-Structured\-Data\-Testing\-Tool).*$ [NC]

# Allow access from [ W3C Markup Validation Service ]. #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(W3C_Validator|Validator\.nu\/LV).*$ [NC]

# Allow access from [ W3C CSS Validation Service ]. #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(W3C_CSS_Validator).*$ [NC]

# Allow users access to the directory containing the pages that handle HTTP error codes. #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(error_documents)\/.*$ [NC]

# Allow users access to the parked "maintenance" page (duh!). #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/park\/index\.php$ [NC]

# During development and maintenance periods, redirect all others to the parked "maintenance" page. #
RewriteRule .* /park/index.php [R=302,L] 

</IfModule>
```

Please, let me know if I missed something, or if there is an error in my code.

Regards,

> *PS: And, no, I’m not worrying about someone spoofing the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string, because this is meant to keep “normal” people from viewing the site. Others would eventually find some way to hack their way in, regardless of how many preventative security measures I take, and no matter how proactive I try to be. My father always warned me, “A thief can steal the salt out of a biscuit, and not even break the crust,
>   ” and “Locks are only for honest people,” So I took heed to his advise, and don't worry so much about hackers anymore. Besides, even if they DO get in, what's the worst that can happen? They see a broken, or unfinished website?*